# Django using the values method with m2m relationships / filtering m2m tables using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, blank=False)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, blank=False)
    books = models.ManyToMany(Books)
```

I am trying to filter the authors so I can return a result set of authors like:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Grisham', books : [{name: 'The Client'},{name: 'The Street Lawyer}], ..]
```

Before I had the m2m relationship on author I was able to query for any number of author records and get all of the values I needed using the values method with only one db query.

But it looks like

```
Author.objects.all().values('name', 'books')
```

would return something like:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Grisham', books :{name: 'The Client'}},{id: 1, name: 'Grisham', books :{name: 'The Street Lawyer'}}]
```

Looking at the docs it doesn't look like that is possible with the values method.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

> Warning Because ManyToManyField attributes and reverse relations can
>   have multiple related rows, including these can have a multiplier
>   effect on the size of your result set. This will be especially
>   pronounced if you include multiple such fields in your values() query,
>   in which case all possible combinations will be returned.

I want to try to get a result set of n size with with the least amount of database hits `authorObject.books.all()` would result in at least n db hits.

Is there a way to do this in django?

I think one way of doing this with the least amount of database hits would be to :

```
authors = Authors.objects.all().values('id')
q = Q()
for id in authors:
   q = q | Q(author__id = id)

#m2m author book table.. from my understanding it is 
#not accessible in the django QuerySet
author_author_books.filter(q)  #grab all of the book ids and author ids with one query
```

Is there a built in way to query the m2m author_author_books table or am I going to have the write the sql?  Is there a way to take advantage of the Q() for doing OR logic in raw sql?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want prefetch_related.  Something like this:

```
authors = Author.objects.prefetch_related('books').all()
```

More on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

If you want to query your author_author_books table, I think you need to specify a "through" table:

```
class BookAuthor(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=127, blank=False)
  books = models.ManyToMany(Books, through=BookAuthor)
```

and then you can query BookAuthor like any other model.

Comment: +1 That looks like it would work but I really don't want to change my table structure.  But changing the structure looks like it would be the best option over raw sql.